# Do piercing weapons go through shields?

Tags: steamworld-heist

The description for the *Bone Piece* weapon in *SteamWorld Heist* says that it "pierces characters" when fired.

Does this piercing effect include characters with metal shields? Or will shots bounce off the shield?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested it out. If the piercing shot strikes a shield on the front side, the shot will ricochet, if it strikes from the rear, the shot will ignore the shield completely(even if it ricochets off another surface and back to the shield's frontside, the shield will no longer protect against that shot). This all assumes the weapon is tagged as character-piercing and not obstacle-piercing.

Comment: After further playing, it appears even cover-piercing weapons cannot pierce shields.